# What is the Swift 3 syntax for creating an AWSTask with a result?

Tags: aws-sdk, swift3, xcode8, aws-sdk-ios

Before Swift 3, my code for creating an AWSTask with a result was something like this:

```
let results = ["resultOne", "resultTwo"]
let task = AWSTask(result: results)
```

But using Swift 3, I'm getting this error message from Xcode 8:

Cannot convert value of type '[String]' to expected argument type '_?'

Has anyone else come across this? Thanks so much!

Comment: try `let results: Any = (["resultOne", "resultTwo"])`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply add `as NSArray` like this:

```
let results = ["resultOne", "resultTwo"] as NSArray
let task = AWSTask(result: results)
```

Because `results` must confirm to Protocol `AnyObject` when define AWSTask:

```
open class AWSTask<ResultType : AnyObject> : NSObject {...}
```

In swift 2.2 `["resultOne", "resultTwo"]` is auto brige to `NSArray`,

But in swift 3.0 you have to brige `[String]` to `NSArray` manually.

This is the explanation:

https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0072-eliminate-implicit-bridging-conversions.md

Comment: Thanks so much! Before reading your answer I noticed the cast to NSArray got rid of the error, but your answer taught me why.